# Encryption container for multiple people

Tags: windows, encryption, containers, restrictions

I was just wondering if anyone may have come across a product that would allow for a container based encryption to be used by multiple people, in a Windows Server setup.

I wanted to see if there might be something like a truecrypt that could handle being accessed by two accounts?

Looking to see if there is a product that would have such properties that would allow only a hand full of users access to the content of the location, but allow for the files to be backed up a normal backup system.  That way if a file had to be restored, the container could be redirected to another location for one of the users to get access to it?  This would allow for access to be restricted beyond the NTFS and file share permissons

Comment: You might want to check this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software).  There seem to be a few options that allow you to have multiple keys per container.

Comment: Not container based but I have seen two items that may be along the same vain

SecureZip and ShareCrypt

Answer (score 0):

[PGP NetShare](http://www.pgp.com/products/netshare/index.html) should be able to do what you are looking for.  It isn't freeware though.  I've used PGP pretty extensively, although not this feature.  PGP works well under normal circumstances.  For power users, it has its share of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The EFS built into any Windows OS XP, 2003 or higher will allow multiple-user EFS.

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-EFS-Windows-2003.html

No need to involve any additional software.

Answer (score 0):

[Atakama.com](https://Atakama.com) supports shareable encryption.   The free version limits the number of profiles you can share with though.